# error when returning const_iterator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am getting an error when I try to deference the constant iterator. I want to be able to return the iterator in the findntoLast iterator than display the values of the linked list by iterating from the new reference to the end of the linked list.

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <forward_list>

using std::forward_list;
typedef std::forward_list<int>::const_iterator constListIt;

#include "LinkedListQ2.h"

int main()
{
    forward_list<int> myList;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    myList.push_front(i);
    constListIt myListIt = myList.begin();
    for( myListIt; myListIt !=  myList.end(); myListIt++)
    cout << *myListIt << endl;
    constListIt newListIt = findntoLast(myList, 5);

    while(newListIt != myList.end())
    {
        cout << *newListIt << endl;
    newListIt++;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* LinkedListQ1.h*/
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_Q1_H_
#define LINKED_LIST_Q1_H_
#include <iterator>
using std::next;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <forward_list>
using std::forward_list;

template<typename T>
typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator findntoLast( forward_list<T> sList,  size_t count )
{
     typedef std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator sListIterator;
         sListIterator newList = sList.begin();

    for(size_t increment = 0; increment < count -1; increment++)
    {
        newList++;
    }

    return newList;
}
#endif
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Expression: forward_list iterators incompatible. I believe it has to do with newListIt and how it was reutrned.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T>
typename [...]::const_iterator findntoLast( forward_list<T> sList, [...])
```

That parameter is passed by value. It means your `findntoLast` works on a *copy* of your original list. When the function returns, that copy gets destroyed. So any iterators that referenced it become invalid.

Take the list by const reference and that problem should go away.

You're also missing a `typename` in the typedef:

```
typedef typename std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator sListIterator;
```

Lastly, take a look at [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), it does what you need already (plus it will take advantage of random access iterators if you ever change your underlying collection type).